# JavaFX pixel pane?

Tags: java, javafx

Is there a way to just make everything snap on top some grid that is pixel by pixel accurate and doesn't resize anything? There is a `GridPane`, but that one just resizes everything to fit things and it doesn't seem to be accurate pixel by pixel.

What I need is something like:

```
pixelPane.add(new Label("THING"), x, y);
```

where `x` and `y` are positions on the pane. If I say something like position 200, 200 then I have another object with position 200,250 but it's 100 pixels in length; I want it to be on *top of the first* object; no resizing or anything.

Comment: You can use a `Pane` and call `setLayoutX()` and `setLayoutY()` on each node you add. Not sure why you would ever want to do something like that, though.

Comment: Ah; nice! Works very nicely.

Comment: As James said though, you should usually really not take that approach! It might seem "easier" if you start out, but it is defiantly not the right way to go.

Comment: Guess I'll have to learn as I go.